# How to move a Core Plot graph

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-plot

[image]I have a Core-Plot Graph within a Mac Application. But the inside table is appearing shifted down and to the left of the containing "frame/border" so that neither of the axis' are showing. I cannot figure out how to change this does anyone know what parameters I need to change to fix this?

Update: Sorry I did not realize I could upload an image, I have done so know and will try your suggestions in the mean-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "inside table". It would be easier to offer suggestions if you could post a screenshot.

Without seeing what's wrong, here are some common areas to look at:

1. If you haven't already done so, look at the example apps included with Core Plot for ideas. The Plot Gallery app has many sample plots and the others are useful, too.
2. You may need to add padding (`paddingLeft`, `paddingBottom`, etc.) on the graph and/or plot area frame. Padding the graph pushes everything in away from the edges of the graph. Padding the plot area frame pushes the plot area in so the axes and titles can hang outside the plot area (the area where the plots are drawn).
3. If you want to keep an axes pinned to a specific place, e.g., the edge of the graph, set up a floating axis. Otherwise make sure the orthogonal coordinate is set (it defaults to 0). For example, the orthogonal coordinate for the x-axis is the y-value where the x-axis crosses the y-axis.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to adjust the padding on the axis not the area frame itself.